# Erro de refência do "this" dentro de uma função filha apos o build no typescript + ReactJs

Tags: typescript, react

Estou com um problema com o "this" após o build utilizando typescript + ReactJs, 
tenho uma função que lê um xmls para salvar no banco, após rastrear o erro descobri que ele corre onde declaro o "this" desta maneira:

```
const _this = this;
```

Obs: preciso o _this pois o setState não é aceito dentro da função, caso eu transformasse a `filerReader.onload` em arrow function ele aprenta erro tambem.

Após o build recebo o seguinte erro:

> :  ReferenceError: this hasn't been initialised - super() hasn't been called
>       at r (assertThisInitialized.js:3)
>       at index.tsx:199
>       at l (runtime.js:45)
>       at Generator._invoke (runtime.js:264)
>       at Generator.e. [as next] (runtime.js:98)
>       at r (asyncToGenerator.js:3)
>       at s (asyncToGenerator.js:25)
>       at asyncToGenerator.js:32
>       at new Promise ()
>       at a. (asyncToGenerator.js:21)

Meu código:

```
 handleInputChangeTeste = async (e: any) => {
try {
  let files = e.target.files[0];
  var filerReader = new FileReader();
  const streches: any = [];
  const _this = this;
  filerReader.onload = async function(e: any) {
    var binary = "";
    var bytes = new Uint8Array(e.target.result);
    var length = bytes.byteLength;
    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      binary += String.fromCharCode(bytes[i]);
    }

    // call 'xlsx' to read the file
    var oFile = XLSX.read(binary, { type: "binary" });

    var pages = _.size(oFile.SheetNames);
    var size = _.size(oFile.Sheets.Página1) - 1;
    for (let index = 0; index <= size; index++) {
      // console.log("aqui length", streches.length);
      for (let j = 0; j < pages; j++) {
        //console.log(oFile.Sheets[oFile.SheetNames[j]]);
        if (oFile.Sheets[oFile.SheetNames[j]]["A" + index] !== undefined) {
          streches.push({
            Lat_inic: oFile.Sheets[oFile.SheetNames[j]]["A" + index].v,
            Lon_inic: oFile.Sheets[oFile.SheetNames[j]]["B" + index].v,
            Lat_fim: oFile.Sheets[oFile.SheetNames[j]]["C" + index].v,
            Lon_fim: oFile.Sheets[oFile.SheetNames[j]]["D" + index].v,
            wildDayLong: oFile.Sheets[oFile.SheetNames[j]]["E" + index].v,
            wildNocturnal: oFile.Sheets[oFile.SheetNames[j]]["F" + index].v,
            domesticDayLong: oFile.Sheets[oFile.SheetNames[j]]["H" + index].v,
            domesticNocturnal: oFile.Sheets[oFile.SheetNames[j]]["I" + index].v,
            domesticTwilight: oFile.Sheets[oFile.SheetNames[j]]["J" + index].v,
            acidentDayLong: oFile.Sheets[oFile.SheetNames[j]]["K" + index].v,
            acidentNocturnal: oFile.Sheets[oFile.SheetNames[j]]["L" + index].v,
          });
        }
      }
    }
    var date = new Date().getTime();
    const strechFinsh = {
      uid: "hhad26451",
      code: `BD-${date}`, //"BD-251138"
      type: "-",
      area: "-", //"25 km"
      registerNumber: "-", //215251
      state: "-", //"São Paulo"
      category: "-", //"Animal"
      lastUpdate: date,
      map: "-", //mapId2
      database: "-", //"Animal",
      deleted: false,
      streches: streches,
    };

    _this.setState({ loadingData: true }, async () => {
      console.log(streches)
      if(streches.length > 0){
        await _this.createStreche(strechFinsh);
      }else{
        showToast("Ops... parece que há dados errados no seu trecho, confira os dados e tente novamente!");
      }
      await _this.getStreches();
    });
  };
  await filerReader.readAsArrayBuffer(files);
} catch (e) {
  console.log("aqui error: ", e);
}
```

};

Comment: use `this.atributo` ou `this.metodo = () => { ... }`, o `this` será sempre o `this`...

Comment: Não se usa `const _self = this`, dentro de um método, const é global. Você provavelmente estava acostumado a trabalhar com javascript nativo e utilizava `var _self = this;` para pegar o this fora de um escopo e usá-lo em outro. Em typescript, a gente não precisa mais fazer isso, pois o escopo é mantido, a variável que é definida como const é é uma constante, use `let variavel=` para trabalhar dentro do escopo do seu método, e `super()` , para poder extender métodos do pai da sua classe... ou `var variavel` se deseja fazer uma variável mutável, independente do escopo.

Comment: Dá [uma lida aqui](https://www.alura.com.br/artigos/entenda-diferenca-entre-var-let-e-const-no-javascript)